# Undefined offset 0

Tags: php, undefined

I have problem with this error script.

```
private function setCentroidCluster(){
    for ($i=0;$i<count($this->centroidCluster);$i++){
        $countObj = 0;
        $x = array();           
        for ($j=0;$j<count($this->objek);$j++){
            if ($this->objek[$j]->getCluster()==$i){
                for ($k=0;$k<count($this->objek[$j]->data);$k++){ // Error
                    $x[$k] += $this->objek[$j]->data[$k];
```

The error is:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 1

The error in line:

```
$x[$k] += $this->objek[$j]->data[$k];
```

Comment: You need to look into the construction of your data structure.

Comment: And perhaps learn to use space bar for indention/making code readable.

Answer (score 1):

First:

`$x` is an empty array. You want to add something at index `$k`. This is undefined. You need to define at least something there. There's a diff between auto-assigning array values and incrementing an existing array element:

```
 for ($k=0;$k<count($this->objek[$j]->data);$k++){
      if ( !isset($x[$k]) )
           $x[$k] = 0; // depending on the type of data[$k] !!!
      $x[$k] += $this->objek[$j]->data[$k];
 }
```

should do the trick.

And as a recommendation, make yourself familiar with `foreach`:

```
  foreach ($this->objek as $obj => $dat )
  {
        if ( $obj->getCluster() == $i )
        {
          foreach ( $dat as $datelem )
              ....
```

etc.